# How do I squeeze gelatine?

Tags: dessert, gelatin

Every recipe I've seen which uses gelatine says to soak and squeeze it, but none of them say *how* to squeeze it. I've only cooked once with gelatine, and I just squeezed it in my hand, but I was worried about losing it all through my fingers and I'm not sure I actually squeezed any water out of it.

Is squeezing it in the fist the correct way? If not, what equipment should I be looking out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always done it with my hands. Just don't let it soak too long, it will still be in one piece and will be generally easy to handle.

Comment: This time I squeezed between both palms rather than in one fist and it worked a lot better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, if you are using leaf gelatine, use your hands after running them under cold water. Separate the leaves before soaking, then grab 'em all and squeeze.

Powder gelatine is a bit harder.  Which are you using?

Comment: I'm using leaf gelatine.

Comment: Far superior type. Good for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the sheet gelatine to stay in one piece before you squeeze the water out is soaking it in ice cold water. Not chilled or room temperature or tap water but ice water.